# WordPress File Upload Form Returning Null

Tags: uploads, forms

I know this has been mentioned a few times but I'm running short of ideas,

For some reason, my form won't upload any file regardless of size or type, I've checked my php.ini, my permissions everything and still stumped,

My code is as follows a basic form:

```
<form method="POST" id="uploadForm" name="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php wp_nonce_field('upload_action', 'upload_nonce') ?>
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="upload_action"/>
<input type="file"  name="latest_accounts"  id="latest_accounts" aria-required="true" multiple="false" class="form-control">
<button class="btn btn-solid btn-sm p-2 mt-4" type="submit">Save Changes</button>
```

Some js:

```
 $('#uploadForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(formData);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: settings.ajaxurl,
        data: formData,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.warn(data);
        }
    });

});
```

PHP Callback

```
 function upload_action(){
$nonce = $_POST['upload_nonce'];
if (! wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'upload_action')) {
        die('Busted!');
}

echo json_encode(
    array(
        $_POST,
        $_FILES,
        $_FILES['latest_accounts'],
        $_FILES['latest_accounts']['name'],
    )
);
die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_upload_action', 'upload_action');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_upload_action', 'upload_action');
```

PHP Ini:

```
;php_admin_flag[log_errors]=on
;php_admin_value[memory_limit]=64M
;php_admin_value[max_execution_time]=120
;php_admin_value[date.timezone]=Europe/Berlin
;php_admin_value[max_input_time]=300
;php_admin_value[post_max_size]=25M
;php_admin_value[upload_max_filesize]=20M
;php_admin_value[max_input_vars]=3000
;php_admin_value[max_file_uploads]=20
;php_admin_value[display_errors]=on
;php_admin_value[file_uploads]=on
```

Permissions are fine, I'm able to upload to the media directory in WordPress as normal, I haven't got to the handle_upload function as of yet that's next.

Result on submission is:

`[{"upload_nonce":"ea89495db1","_wp_http_referer":"\/assessment\/","member_id":"1558","action":"upload_action"},null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]`

Enqueue Scripts:

```
 wp_enqueue_script('scripts', get_theme_file_uri() . '/scripts.js', array( 'jquery-ui-tabs' ), time(), true);
  global $wp_query;
  wp_localize_script(
     'scripts',
     'settings',
     array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            'posts' => json_encode($wp_query->query_vars),
            'current_page' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
        )
 );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: if it doesn't do what you want it to do, what does it do instead? I see you're trying to log information but you've not shared any of that in your question, Also where is the `action` parameter? It looks like you're makingg an AJAX request to the old admin ajax legacy API but nowhere do you actually tell it the action you want it to handle. How is it meant to know you wanted `upload`? Is there a reason you used the old API instead of making an AJAX request to the REST API?

Comment: Whoops sorry about that, added the action to the form and the result I get, as well as everything else.